# regexp function behavior using a string variable to define an expression

Tags: regex, tcl

Searching a files contents to remove lines between pre-compile directives that have a $DEBUG character.

Typical pattern for data lines searching for:

```
#IFDEF $DEBUG_MY_TEST
.... lines ...
#ENDIF


#IFDEF DEBUG_MY_issues for_sam
.... lines ...
#ENDIF

#IFDEF CMER for_max
.... lines ....
#ENDIF
```

This expression test works:

```
if { [regexp -lineanchor -nocase -- {^[ \t]*#IFDEF[ \t]+[\$]?DEBUG.*} $oline_strpd ] == 1 } {
  set remove_to_cust_endif $oline_strpd; # sanity check
  continue;
}
```

I believe the problem is using the `$` character in the string variable pattern.

Making a search using this string variable method is not working? :

```
set RE_STRNG [format "\{^\[ \\t\]*#IFDEF\[ \\t\]+\[\\$\]?DEBUG.*\}"]
if { [regexp -lineanchor -nocase -- $RE_STRNG $oline_strpd ] == 1 } {
  set remove_to_cust_endif $oline_strpd; # sanity check
  continue;
}
```

In a previous line in the code using this string variable method is working:

```
set RE_STRNG [format "\{^\[ \\t\]*#IFDEF\[ \\t\]+CMER\[ \\t\]+%s\}" $is_cmer_name ]; # insert name into the search pattern
if { [regexp -lineanchor -nocase -- $RE_STRNG $oline_strpd ] == 1 && [llength $oline_strpd] == 3 } {
      set print_to_cust_endif $oline_strpd; # sanity check
      continue;
}
```

Comment: What langauge are you using? And please format your question.

Comment: When you wrote the question you saw a preview of the formatted text. Don't submit the question until it looks like you want it to look. You could also find a "Markdown Editing Help" button (the orange one with a question mark) and a "How to format" box on the right hand side. Please read this information to learn how to format your question, especially code, so that others are able to read and understand the question and to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Um, since you don't have any replacement to be done, you can simply put the regexp itself.

This works:

```
set RE_STRNG {^[ \t]*#IFDEF[ \t]+[\$]?DEBUG.*}
if { [regexp -lineanchor -nocase -- $RE_STRNG $oline_strpd ] == 1 } {
    set remove_to_cust_endif $oline_strpd; # sanity check
    continue;
}
```

Or if you want to use `format`, you can still keep the braces:

```
set RE_STRNG [format {^[ \t]*#IFDEF[ \t]+[\$]?DEBUG.*}]
if { [regexp -lineanchor -nocase -- $RE_STRNG $oline_strpd ] == 1 } {
    set remove_to_cust_endif $oline_strpd; # sanity check
    continue;
}
```

I'm not sure why it isn't working, but the following works:

```
set RE_STRNG [format "^\[ \\t\]*#IFDEF\[ \\t\]+\[\\$\]?DEBUG.*"]
if { [regexp -lineanchor -nocase -- $RE_STRNG $oline_strpd ] == 1 } {
    set remove_to_cust_endif $oline_strpd; # sanity check
    continue;
}
```

I tested some more and interestingly enough, if you insert `[format "\{^\[ \\t\]*#IFDEF\[ \\t\]+\[\\$\]?DEBUG.*\}"]` somewhere in the file you have the lines, and use this:

```
set RE_STRNG [format "\{.*\}"]
if { [regexp -lineanchor -nocase -- $RE_STRNG $oline_strpd ] == 1 } {
    set remove_to_cust_endif $oline_strpd; # sanity check
    continue;
}
```

The only line which matches is the one you have just inserted, which makes me believe that the regex is trying to match `[format "{.*}"]` in the text (with the format). So I believe that because of the substitution, Tcl executes the command `format` before putting it in the regex, while without it, it is inserting the whole things with the format command in the regex.

Comment: Jerry -Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @user2406910 Were you able to solve the issues you were having using this?

Comment: Thanks All for your help,

Comment: This is my solution -

Comment: My solution based on the help above: function getUnits(num) {
  var units = null;
  numprt = num.replace(/[A-z]+$/,"");
  if(num.length != numprt.length) {
    units = num.replace(numprt,"");
  }
  return(units);
}

Comment: @user2406910 ok? Not sure why you changed languages midway though, because that's not Tcl